# What is wrong on my code, I'm expected to print the output in int but it seems not?

Tags: c, printf

This is my code, and I still keep on looking what's wrong, I'm a beginner and I want to learn:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;

    printf("Input: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("\n%d", &a);
    a+=2;
    printf("\n%d", &a);
    a+=4;
    printf("\n%d", &a);
    a+=2;
    printf("\n%d", &a);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Input: 10

-1078169908
-1078169908
-1078169908
-1078169908
```

Comment: You don't need `&` to print integers

Comment: @Arc676 only if scanf fails.

Comment: It's also very odd to prefix your format strings with newlines.  Normally one would put those at the end of the format string.

Comment: Did you read the warnings?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to pass the address of `a` to `printf()` to print the content.

Change

```
printf("\n%d", &a);
```

to

```
 printf("\n%d", a);
```

Also, you should be checking the return value of `scanf()`. In case `scanf()` fails, you'll be invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by accessing an unitialized local variable.

That said, `int main()` should at least be `int main(void)` to conform to the standards.

Comment: plus one for the undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Ehsan Don;t say like that. It sounds like the answer itself has UB. Cheers ;)

Comment: I had a "learning experience" yesterday: "An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the
function has no parameters." C11 §6.7.6.3 14 or IOWs `int main()` and `int main(void)` are the same.  So "int main() should at least be int main(void)" is not needed.

Comment: @chux The problem here is that the empty list isn't in *a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function*. Note how [this example](http://ideone.com/wpfv9a) compiles, yet [this one](http://ideone.com/UY4QOf) does not?

Answer (score 3):

Just to add some points to others' answers :

> & operator gives the address of a variable

so when you say :

```
scanf("%d",&a);
```

You actually tell the compiler to pass the address of variable `a` to `scanf` function in order to `scanf` changes the value of variable `a` because if you call `scanf` like this :

```
scanf("%d",a);
```

You are just passing the value of a to `scanf` so it can't change the value of `a`.

But when you use `printf`, function `printf` need not to change the value of variable `a` so it's right to invoke `printf` like this and it will compile successfully:

```
printf("%d",a);
```

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value) ( Actually this syntax is used in some languages )

Comment: I think you do a fine job at explaining this, and this answer would be better without the link to a subtly different concept...

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this :-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()             
{
           int a;

           printf("Input: ");
           scanf("%d", &a);
           printf("\n%d", a);
           a+=2;
           printf("\n%d", a);
           a+=4;
           printf("\n%d", a);
           a+=2;
           printf("\n%d", a);
           return 0;
}
```

`printf ()` function is used for printing message on screen that is why we don't use `&` operator in `printf ()` function `&` operator is used when you take inputs from user like in `scanf ()` function so, what you have to do is to remove `&` in every `printf ()` function rest is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Few tips for you:

- When you use `scanf ()` to get value from user and store it, always use like this: `&a`
- When you print any value using `printf ()` never put `&a`. Use only `a`.

So remove `&a` from `printf ()` and write `a`

Comment: Mostly correct. `scanf` takes a pointer, so a pointer to `char` should be passed directly, not with `&`. And, of course, you may actually want to print a pointer value, in which case you might use `&` in `printf`.

Comment: The first tip is invalid. In the case of `%s`, "the corresponding argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of a character array large enough to accept the sequence and a terminating null character". `char str; scanf("%s", &a);` is silly as `&a` isn't used to express a pointer to the first element of an array larger than 1 character, and the only string that array can store is an empty one. Using `char a[N]; scanf("%s", &a);` is even worse, because `&a` is not "a pointer to the initial element", as your compiler likely warns. **In summary, `scanf("%s", &a);` is *ALWAYS* a mistake.**